LoadLibrary returning NULL, error 126, possible path issue
I was working with a DLL and can't get it to work, due to it returning NULL when I try to load it in.
After trying to format the name in many ways, like using a WCHAR array, a wchar_t array, and just casting the name into a LPCWSTR, all with both the full path and just the name, it keeps bringing up the same error, 126.
Here is the code:
HINSTANCE library = NULL;
library = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\libraryTest\\x64\\Debug\\library.dll");
if (library == NULL) {
    printf("Failure loading the library");
    return -1;
}

If anyone can see where the problem is, I would appreciate it, and please ask if you need any extra piece of code or test.

I don't use windows, but I guess you can get some more info with GetLastError.

Does the DLL depend on other DLL's? Perhaps it's those dependencies that fail to load?

@pptaszni they already use GetLastError (not show in their code). LoadLibrary doesn't return an error code but a handle or NULL in case of failure.
